# Passing values between multiple ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am newbie in Swift so probably asking a dumb question...

I have a UICellViewController in which I have following method

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        print("tapped got at index: \(indexPath.row) with tag: \(cell.tag) ")
         //var viewController = CalculatorViewController()
        //storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A")

        if indexPath.row == cellLabels.count - 1{
             let viewController = VC1()
            viewController.selection = cellLabels[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

        }
        else{
            let viewController = VC2()
            viewController.selection = cellLabels[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

        }



    }
```

Essentially, I have two ViewController classes VC1 and VC2 of type ViewController
and based on which cell is clicked, I want to present the right view.
So, that is the intention..

Now in each of these classes VC1 and VC2, I have a UILabel (selection) which I am also trying to set above.

But when I try to run the class.. the code compiles and runs..
it crashes where I am trying to set the label

```
self.label.text = selection //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong? 
What's the right way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you connected your label as an IBOutlet? Or have you created it programmatically ?

Comment: @Mansi: yes..I did..

Comment: @Mansi: But I probably might have not done it correctly.. 
Whats the right way to have multiple views based on which cell is clicked and pass data between these views?

Comment: One possible reason for the crash can be that your IBOutlet is not connected properly. So try removing the connection and reconnecting it from your storyboard/xib.

Comment: Where are you calling self.label.text = selection ?

Comment: In the VC1 and VC2 classes..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172131/discussion-between-mansi-and-fraz).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the IBOutlet of another ViewController from one ViewController.
Here you are accessing selection which is UILabel outlet.
So you need to take one variable in VC1 and VC2 controller. And need to access that variable like how you are accessing section variable..

```
//In VC1 and VC2
var sectionLabel: String?

//While passing value
viewController.sectionLabel = cellLabels[indexPath.row]
```

Another try is. Remove detailsLabel outlet from here and reconnect it. see image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.. but isnt that what I am doing.. I have a variable selection in VC1 and VC2.. and then I am setting those in main view controller as you stated?

Comment: What is selection? is it IBOutlet?

Comment: ```var selection: String?
    @IBOutlet private weak var detailsLabel : UILabel!
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.detailsLabel.text = selection
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }```

Comment: selection is a string.. then there is  a label.. which I am trying to set

Comment: Ok check your detailsLabel outlet? Its not set properly. Delete it and again take it.